# C# and LINQ.XML Select from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've been struggling to find out how to select multiple values from an XML file, compare them to a special value and then do something. So far I just managed to select a single value but I also need a different one in the same select, I hope you can assist me

XML Structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<userConnectionSettings version="1" lastApplicationUrl="xxx" lastIdentity="yyy">
    <application url="xxx" lastFolderId="zzz">
        <user name="test" domain="domain.tld" lastFolderId="yyy" />
    </application>
</userConnectionSettings>
```

Now basically, what i want to do is read the `lastApplicationURL` and the domain value. I managed to do the `lastApplicationURL` but i can't seem to select the domain and i don't know how to get that value properly. Here's my code :

```
XDocument foDoc = XDocument.Load(FrontOfficePath);

foreach (var FOurl in foDoc.Descendants("userConnectionSettings"))
{
    string FOappURL = (string)FOurl.Attribute("lastApplicationUrl");

    if (FOappURL == "something")
    {
        TODO
    }
    else
    {
         TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `FOurl.Element("application").Element("user").Attribute("domain")`?

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `domain` attribute, in two different ways :
1 - Like @Juharr comment :

```
foreach (var FOurl in foDoc.Descendants("userConnectionSettings"))
{
    string domain = FOurl
        .Element("application")
        .Element("user")
        .Attribute("domain")
        .Value;
....
}
```

Or, by getting descendant of `application` and select the first item, like :

```
foreach (var FOurl in foDoc.Descendants("userConnectionSettings"))
{
    string domain = FOurl.Descendants("application")
        .Select(x => x.Element("user").Attribute("domain").Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();
....
}
```

i hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Ahhh i understand, perfect, thank you very much for the clarification. I wasn't aware you had to select it like this (via Attribute). Worked perfectly :)!

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Application> applications = doc.Descendants("application").Select(x => new Application()
            {
                url = (string)x.Attribute("url"),
                id = (string)x.Attribute("lastFolderId"),
                name = (string)x.Element("user").Attribute("name"),
                domain = (string)x.Element("user").Attribute("domain"),
                folder = (string)x.Element("user").Attribute("lastFolderId")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Application
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string folder { get; set; }
    }
}
```